# Golang DB connection with AWS SSM Parameters and context

Tags: sql, go, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm working on setting up an app backend that's deployed automatically using infrastructure-as-code and a ci/cd pipeline. As a result of that I need the app server to gather DB credentials automatically. This is my first time working with the AWS Go SDK and I want to get the code as close to production ready as possible.

Credentials to use the AWS SDK are set when instances are spun-up so this only needs to set a base parameters for the file root (e.g. `/app/db/`) and the aws region to connect which are both pulled form a .env file. The sdk is then used to pull encrypted strings from the AWS SSM Parameter Store and use them to write a connection string and connect to the database. I also included a small server that pings the db and tells the user if it's connected.

dbConnector.go:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

const timeout = 5

// Database abstracts sqlx connection
type Database struct{
    *sqlx.DB
}

// ConnectToDB creates a db connection with a predefined timeout
func ConnectToDB(ctx context.Context) (*Database, error) {
    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(ctx, timeout*time.Second)
    defer cancelFn()

    conn, err := sqlx.ConnectContext(ctx, "pgx", configString(ctx))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &Database{conn}, nil

}

// Connected pings server and returns bool response status
func (db *Database) Connected(ctx context.Context) bool {
    err := db.PingContext(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

dbConfig.go:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ssm"
)

const (
    baseRegion  = "AWS_REGION"
    baseRoot    = "AWS_ROOT"
    baseConfig  = "base_config"
    basePath    = "."

    ssmHost     = "host"
    ssmDB       = "postgres"
    ssmPort     = "port"
    ssmUser     = "user"
    ssmPassword = "password"
)

type awsSSM struct {
    *ssm.SSM
}

// Create database connection string based on AWS_ROOT and remote SSM parameters
func configString(ctx context.Context) string {
    loadBaseConfig()

    sess := session.New()
    svc := awsSSM{ssm.New(sess, &aws.Config{
            Region: aws.String(viper.GetString(baseRegion)),
    })}

    configString := fmt.Sprintf("database=%s host=%s port=%d user=%s password = %s",
        ssmDB,
        svc.param(ctx, ssmHost),
        atoui(svc.param(ctx, ssmPort)),
        svc.param(ctx, ssmUser),
        svc.param(ctx, ssmPassword),
    )

    return configString
}

// Pull AWS_ROOT and AWS_REGION from .env file, all other config happens on instance spin-up
func loadBaseConfig() {
    viper.SetConfigName(baseConfig)
    viper.AddConfigPath(basePath)

    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

// Get SSM Parameter with context timeout
func (svc *awsSSM) param(ctx context.Context, p string) string {
    output, err := svc.GetParameterWithContext(ctx, &ssm.GetParameterInput{
            Name: aws.String(viper.GetString(baseRoot) + p),
            WithDecryption: aws.Bool(true),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return ""
    }

    return aws.StringValue(output.Parameter.Value)
}

// String to unsigned int16
func atoui(s string) uint16 {
    n, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return 0

    }
    return (uint16)(n)
}
```

main.go:

```
package main 

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

// Server struct for storing database, mux, and logger
type Server struct{
    db *Database
    mux *httprouter.Router
    log *log.Logger
}

// Create router and environment then serve
func main() {
    s := Server{
        log: log.New(os.Stdout, log.Prefix(), log.Flags()),
        mux: httprouter.New(),
    }

    db, err := ConnectToDB(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        s.log.Println(err)
    }

    s.db = db
    
    s.mux.GET("/", s.index())

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8050", s.mux))
}

// Index is a closure that returns a function that checks the database connection and writes status to user
func (s *Server) index() httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
        if s.db.Connected(r.Context()) {
            fmt.Fprint(w, "Connected!")
        } else {
            http.Error(w, "Error connecting to database", http.StatusNotFound)
            s.log.Println("Error connectiong to database")
        }
    }
}
```